# Regenerate linux host fingerprint

Tags: linux, ssh, fingerprint, puppet

Is it possible to change a hosts ssh fingerprint?  An example of needing to do this would be a virtual machine clone having the same fingerprint as the source of the clone; which causes problems for applications such as Puppet.

Answer (score 5):

which distribution of linux you have? if it is ubuntu, you can remove all the host keys /etc/ssh/ssh_host*

then reconfigure the package.

```
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

other distributions are similar. you can either reconfigure the package or even reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

The fingerprint for your machine is most likely located in `/etc/ssh` under

- `ssh_host_rsa_key`, `ssh_host_dsa_key` or
- `ssh_host_key.pub`

You should be able to manually change the file and restart the SSH daemon. A reinstallation of the SSH server should also generate a new host key.